# How to know if mongodb needs authentication?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

When you try to authenticate the user against a database, if the mongod is not started with the --auth parameter I get the error: Authentication failed!

So is there a way to know if the database needs authentication?

Something like that:

```
        DB db = moClient.getDB(moClientURI.getDatabase());                         
        if (db.needsAuthentication()){
            db.authenticate(username, password.toCharArray());
            if (db.isAuthenticated()){
            //do something                
            } else {} // authentication failed                
        }
```

Comment: I am not really sure, but [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-java-driver) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-authentication-access-to-mongodb) examples might be helpful.

Comment: Nope, already checked those links. It doesn't tell you how to know if mongodb needs authentication. Of course I can run a command and check if I get the 'authenticaion failed' to see if it needs auth but this is not a convenient way to do.

Comment: you can get parameters the server was started with with db.serverCmdLineOpts() or db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got the same problem and this is the way I solved it:

```
private void authenticateMongo(String username, String password) throws IOException, AuthenticationException
{
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("admin");

    if (username.equals("") &&  password.equals(""))
    {
        //As no user name and password was supplied, we consider that authentication is disabled
        //But now we need to validate if it's really without authentication
        try
        {
            mongoClient.getDatabaseNames();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Login or password is invalid");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        boolean authenticationOK = db.authenticate(username, password.toCharArray());

        if (!authenticationOK)
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Login or password is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: db.authenticate method is deprecated in more recent Java libs

Comment: How about the anonymous has authentication on other databases except admin

Comment: @ZhaoYi in that case you will need to execute the above code against all the databases